# Different behaviour between two ways of dropping duplicate values in a dataframe

Tags: pandas

I tested two ways of dropping duplicated rows in a dataframe but they didn't obtain the same result and I don't understand why.

First code:

```
file_df1 = open('df1.csv', 'r')
df1_list = []

for line in fila_df1:
    new_line = line.rsplit(',')
    df1_firstcolumn = new_line[0]
    if df1_firstcolumn not in df1_list:
        df1_list.append(df1_firstcolumn)
    #else:
        #print('firstcolumn: ' + df1_firstcolumn + ' is duplicated')

file_df1.close()
```

The second-way using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv', header=None, names=['firstcolumn','second','third','forth'])
df1.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

I obtained more unique values using pandas.

Comment: can you show the output for both ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way you post will "drop duplicates" when duplicates occur based on data in the first column only.

The pandas [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) function by default is checking that values in all four columns have been duplicated.  The version below will remove duplicates based on the first column only.

```
df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['firstcolumn'], inplace=True)
```